# Linux Mint Cinnamon runs in Fallback Mode

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

My Linux Mint version is (cat /etc/linuxmint/info)

```
RELEASE=18.3
CODENAME=sylvia
EDITION="Cinnamon 64-bit"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit
```

My hardware spec is (sudo lshw -c video)

```
*-display               
   description: 3D controller
   product: GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:32 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

The Nvidia driver mannually installed is ( sudo nvidia-smi )
[image]

However,

I have

[image]

glxinfo shows me

```
name of display: :0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

Any suggestion for this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Installing Nvidia-390.12 through Driver Manager fixes this issue.

[image]

Comment: -1 for You don't describe how you managed to pull version 390 into Driver Manager.

Comment: @Vlastimil, thank you for reminding me this.
You can do "sudo apt-get update" to pull version 390 into Driver Manager.

Comment: BTW,
I also add the following content to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off

ref:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau

Comment: nouveau solved my problem with cinnamon on a T61p